# How can I change the parameters passed to CMake during the "Build All Projects" command?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

I am new to both Visual Studio Code and CMake and I can't seem to find the settings that Visual Studio Code uses when deciding what parameters to pass to CMake for the "build all projects" command, found in the context menu when right clicking a [CMakeLists.txt](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#organization) file. In particular, the first time I compile (which fails) the parameters are different from the second time I compile (also fails). The first time I get:

```
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -Sc:/Users/Richard/source/repos/vmdevirt-vtil -Bc:/Users/Richard/source/repos/vmdevirt-vtil/build -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -T host=x64 -A win32
```

and if there is already a build file from failed compilation:

```
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/Users/Richard/source/repos/vmdevirt-vtil/build --config Debug --target vmdevirt-vtil -j 26 --
```

How can I select which options (preferably using a convenient preset like "MSVC x64 C++20" are passed to CMake using this command?

Comment: The first command line you show is **configuration** command. The second command line is **building** command. So, which command line you want to adjust?

Comment: Oh, I suppose the second line must have been present farther down in the output of the first build, buried under the output from configuration. Can I edit both of them?

Comment: Yes, you could modify aspects of both command lines. About preset settings you could read [that article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cmake-presets-integration-in-visual-studio-and-visual-studio-code/#cmake-presets-in-the-cmake-tools-extension-for-visual-studio-code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying CMake parameters can be done with Microsoft's own CMake Tools extension using `CMake: Select Variant` and a number of `CMake: * Preset` options. The preset options will only be present if there is a valid *CMakePresets.json* file in the same directory as the base *CMakeLists.txt* file for the workspace.